# Tuples of closed continuous intervals

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Say I have the following list of numbers:

```
my_array = [0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 70]
```

I would like to find every closed interval containing **consecutive integers without gaps** in this list. If for any number in the list there are multiple such intervals, we **only retain the largest** of any such intervals. The correct answer above should be:

```
[0,   0]
[3,   4]
[7,  10]
[20, 22]
[70, 70]
```

To see this, note for example:

- The closed interval `[0,0]` contains the integer `0`, contains no gaps, and none of its members are contained in any other closed interval.
- The closed interval `[3,4]` contains no gaps and its members are not contained in any other closed interval with no gaps that is larger than itself.

How can I do this in numpy? I started writing an algorithm that uses `np.diff(my_array)` to detect transitions in the array, but it fails on corner cases such as intervals containing only one item.

Comment: how you define, every closed continuous interval??, what is the rule??

Comment: @Hackaholic I significantly expanded the OP to clarify what I mean. let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: got it now, its clear now

Comment: I would start a counter and move the counter through the list. Whenever it stops, all numbers that it covered get a consecutive number. Put these numbers in a dictionary with the original number in the list. Then print the min, max of the dictionary entries for the specific counts.

Comment: Why dont you code it in pure python. It's a 15 lines implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a numpy install handy, but this is the approach that I would take. First handle the case of an empty array separately. Sort the array if it isn't already sorted and use `np.diff` to compute the differences.

```
0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10,  20, 21, 22,  70
  3  1  3  1  1  1   10   1   1   48
```

Test the differences for being `> 1`.

```
  1  0  1  0  0  0    1   0   0    1
```

To get the beginnings of the intervals, put a `1` at the beginning and select the corresponding array items. To get the ends, put a `1` at the end and select the corresponding array items.

```
0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10,  20, 21, 22,  70
1  1  0  1  0  0   0    1   0   0    1
0  3     7             20           70

0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10,  20, 21, 22,  70
1  0  1  0  0  0   1    0   0   1    1
0     4           10           22   70
```

Implementation (largely by user815423426):

```
def get_intervals(my_array):
  my_diff = np.diff(my_array)>1
  begins  = np.insert(my_diff, 0, 1)
  ends    = np.insert(my_diff, -1, 1)
  return np.array(np.dstack((my_array[begins], my_array[ends])))

my_array = np.array([0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 70])
> get_intervals(my_array)
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 7, 10],
       [20, 22],
       [70, 70]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure python implementation:

```
def findContinuousIntervals(numbers):
    if not numbers:
        return []

    sortedNumbers = sorted(numbers)

    result = [(sortedNumbers[0], sortedNumbers[0])]
    for n in sortedNumbers:
        a, b = result[-1]
        if abs(b - n) <= 1:
            result[-1] = (a, n)
        else:
            result.append((n, n))
    return result
```